# Parsing SQL into a hierachial result to analyze it

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, parsing

Is there any library (prefferably in Python) which can parse SQL queries (the PostgreSQL kind), and give me a structured representation of them? There is [sqlparse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse), but that doesn't allow me to easily figure out (say) the table that a query is using. I only need support for `SELECT` queries, but some of them can be quite complex.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you are asking for?

Answer (score 2):

The [select_parser.py](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyparsing/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/examples/select_parser.py) example that comes with pyparsing will give you a ParseResults data structure of the statement. Here are the embedded test cases:

```
select * from xyzzy where z > 100
select * from xyzzy where z > 100 order by zz
select * from xyzzy
select z.* from xyzzy
select a, b from test_table where 1=1 and b='yes'
select a, b from test_table where 1=1 and b in (select bb from foo)
select z.a, b from test_table where 1=1 and b in (select bb from foo)
select z.a, b from test_table where 1=1 and b in (select bb from foo) order by b,c desc,d
select z.a, b from test_table left join test2_table where 1=1 and b in (select bb from foo)
select a, db.table.b as BBB from db.table where 1=1 and BBB='yes'
select a, db.table.b as BBB from test_table,db.table where 1=1 and BBB='yes'
select a, db.table.b as BBB from test_table,db.table where 1=1 and BBB='yes' limit 50
```

The results are structured into different components of the input statement, and the named fields can be accessed like object attributes (`result.table`:  `'XYZZY'`, `result.where_expr`: `['z', '>', '100']`, etc.). Here are the results from the first 3 tests:

```
select * from xyzzy where z > 100
['SELECT', ['*'], 'FROM', 'xyzzy', 'WHERE', ['z', '>', '100']]
- columns: ['*']
- from: ['xyzzy']
- table: ['xyzzy']
- where_expr: ['z', '>', '100']


select * from xyzzy where z > 100 order by zz
['SELECT', ['*'], 'FROM', 'xyzzy', 'WHERE', ['z', '>', '100'], 'ORDER', 'BY', [['zz']]]
- columns: ['*']
- from: ['xyzzy']
- order_by_terms: [['zz']]
  [0]:
    ['zz']
    - order_key: zz
- table: ['xyzzy']
- where_expr: ['z', '>', '100']


select * from xyzzy
['SELECT', ['*'], 'FROM', 'xyzzy']
- columns: ['*']
- from: ['xyzzy']
- table: ['xyzzy']
```

It was written to the SQL dialect for SQLite, but adapting to Postgres shouldn't be too terrible.